# Cordova InAppBrowser v4+ event loadstart not firing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm tring to use inappbrowser v4 or v5 but loadstart event dose not fire :

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('ok'); });
```

Once I use v3.2.0 it works fine, what i'm I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ionic wrapper](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) for this plugin. Then add listener in this way:

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {}

openBrowser() {
    const ref = this.iab.create('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    ref.on('loadstart').subscribe(() => {
        console.log('Load start fired!');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
constructor(private inappbrowser: InAppBrowser) {}


customFunction(){
    this.inappbrowser = this.browser.create("https://stackoverflow.com/", '_blank', { location: 'yes' };

    this.inappbrowser.on("loadstart")
      .subscribe(
        (event_data) => {
          console.log(event_data);
          if (event_data.url.indexOf("checkyoururlhere") > -1) 
          {
             this.inappbrowser.close();
          }
        },
        err => {
          console.log("InAppBrowser loadstart Event Error: " + err);
        });

}
```